# Proxy setting in visual studio 2013 config file

Tags: proxy, web-config

I was trying to add third party web service reference in my application, got proxy error. when I uncheck IE proxy setting then htttps service reference is getting added, but still could not run my application. I tried adding proxy setting in web config file but no luck. Could any one suggest me.

Comment: Were you adding reference to a WCF service? and by saying you did set the proxy, do you mean setting BasicHttpBinding.ProxyAddress for your WCF client settings?

Comment: Try showing examples of what you've tried. Config files, links to tutorials. Any more information would help greatly.

Answer (score 0):

assuming you just call a web service

```
<system.net>
        <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true">
            <proxy usesystemdefault="True" bypassonlocal="True"/>
        </defaultProxy>
    </system.net>
```

If you are having a WCF Client then set

```
BasicHttpBinding.ProxyAddres
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. It works. I just tryied this and it works.

```
<system.net>
<settings>

<ipv6 enabled="true"/>
<servicePointManager expect100Continue="false"/>
</settings>

<defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true" enabled="true">

<proxy usesystemdefault="True" />

</defaultProxy>
```